# inline editable grid in angularjs simple program

Tags: angularjs

here i am trying to display my code in a table using ng-grid but i am getting an error like

```
  GET file:///C:/Users/krishna/Desktop/grid/ng-grids.css net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
    Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

     http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.16/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%…gleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.16%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A381)
```

here is my code what i tried

```
<html ng-app="myApp">  
  <head lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Getting Started With ngGrid Example</title>            
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.16/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ng-grids.css" />
    <script>
      var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid','ngRoute']);
      app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
          $scope.myData = [
              {name: "Ajith", age: 50},
              {name: "rajini", age: 43},
              {name: "araya", age: 27},
              {name: "madi", age: 29},
              {name: "cha", age: 34}
          ];
          $scope.gridOptions = { data: 'myData' };
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

i have to view the data which is availabe in the script, i am new to angularjs for developing an application based upon grid help to gain knowledge in angularjs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You inject 'ngGrid', but you never include this module in your app, so angular cannot find it. You have to include the following files in your header:

- ng-grid.js
- ng-grid.css if you want the pretty styling shown in the tutorials
- jQuery

A working example would be (see the [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/HILHI3aLda1Cvc9EakBX?p=preview%20plunk)):

```
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Getting Started With ngGrid Example</title>
    <link data-require="ng-grid@2.0.14" data-semver="2.0.14" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/v2.0.14/ng-grid.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.16/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.2.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="ng-grid@2.0.14" data-semver="2.0.14" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/v2.0.14/build/ng-grid.js"></script>
    <style>
      .gridStyle {
        height: 300px
      }
    </style>
    <script>
      var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
      app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.myData = [
          {name: "Ajith", age: 50},
          {name: "rajini", age: 43},
          {name: "araya", age: 27},
          {name: "madi", age: 29},
          {name: "cha", age: 34}
        ];

        $scope.gridOptions = {
          data: 'myData'
        };
      });
   </script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-grid="gridOptions" class="gridStyle"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

I removed 'ngRoute' since it isn't actually used in the example, but you can add it in a similar way.

On a side note, the plunks on the ng-grid homepage do not work because they point to a nonexistent script. This might or might not be intended, since ng-grid is depreciated in favor of its newer version, ui-grid.

Comment: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.16/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%…gleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.16%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A381)

Comment: file://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/v2.0.14/ng-grid.css Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
file://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/v2.0.14/build/ng-grid.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: @MohanGopi I did not prepend the reference addresses with "http:", which works on plunker, but not in a local file. My bad, fixed this.

Comment: it work perfect now and i have a doubt is it possible to add a coloumn and reffer it in function like  $scope.myData = [
          {name: "Ajith", age: 50,edit:delete},
 {name: "cha", age: 34:edit:delete}
        ];

Comment: and here delet is a button while using ngclik it should invoke the function

Comment: It is possible, you can define a template for displaying your rows or cells and add a correcsponding ng-click directive there.

Comment: can you give me some example

Comment: i need two button like delete and add button in top of my table

Comment: @MohanGopi Nope :) This goes beyond the scope of the original question; also, this is your work, I'm not going to write your entire project for you. Here is the ng-grid tutorial with a lot of examples (including in-place-editing btw): http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-grid/